# Converse to vectorization of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

The vectorization of a matrix is a well known operation in linear algebra. 
What is the reverse operation called?

Comment: [amalgamation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&q=amalgamation&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: In Matlab the word "[reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)" is used.  If no standard term is available that might be a good term to use.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry thank you. Can you please cite a reference?

Comment: no, because i've never seen it used before. i usually 'stick' vectors together to make a matrix.

Comment: I've seen  $A = {\rm mat}(a)$ and $a={\rm vec}(A)$ in journal articles.

Comment: @greg Thanks, but the term matrization means tensor unfolding. I'm looking for the term for mat(a).